# Bootstrap 3: Change vertical ordering of .col-X elements when collapsing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following layout when on a large display:

```
AAA BBB
AAA CCC
```

(all A's, all B's, and all C's form one div, so there are 3 elements here)

Now when this collapses I want it to become

```
BBB
AAA
AAA
CCC
```

I tried specifying the elements in this order in the HTML, but then the best I could manage to get for the expanded view was (using .push-X classes)

```
AAA BBB
AAA
    CCC
```

The only solutions I can think of are moving things around by JS, or having duplicates of `CCC` at the correct position and showing and hiding them depending on viewport size.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">BBB</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">AAA</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 ">AAA</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 ">CCC</div>
</div>
```

That will work.

How is it done?...
Firstly you need to arrange your content first and foremost for mobile (so consider mobile the 'natural' order i.e.

```
BBB
AAA
AAA
CCC
```

Then, when you expand to desktop you'll get this:

```
BBB AAA  <--- wrong order
AAA CCC
```

So, you then need to swap the order by pushing the `BBB` content to the right, and pulling the `AAA` content to the left

```
BBB------>.
.<------AAA
```

Comment: That would work if the `AAA`s were two divs, but they're not. They're one div with around twice the height of `BBB` and `CCC`.