# How to reorder bootstrap columns vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I'm trying to build the following layout in Bootstrap v3:

```
|  Small       |   Large            |
|--------------|--------------------|
| [A         ] | [A      ][B      ] |
| [A.1       ] | [A.1             ] |
| [B         ] |                    |
```

Although this has been asked many previous times before...

- [How do I change Bootstrap 3 column order on mobile layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20171408/1366033)
- [Reordering divs responsively with Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18514922/1366033)
- [Bootstrap 3: Change vertical ordering of .col-X elements when collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21018272/1366033)
- [Bootstrap 3 grid collapse order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23688923/1366033)

All of those answers have relied on using bootstrap's [push | pull](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering) classes, which move things left and right within a row.  If we take the advice within those threads and start with the mobile layout above, the full width A.1 section will take up the whole 2nd row on a wide layout, at which point shifting things right and left doesn't do any good, excepting hiding those items off screen.

> [image: Example]

**Q**: Is there anyway to shift an item vertically depending on the screen size?

#### Demo in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/b66dwa1L/) | StackSnippets

```css
.a, .b {  border: 1px solid lightgrey;}
.a { color: green;}
.b { color: blue;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm-6 a">Section A</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 a">More Info about Section A</div>
    <div class="col col-sm-6 b">Section B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: I have not so much time, but in bootstrap v4, it has a class called order-x and also you can use it with resolutions, (order-md-X). If it exist on bootstrap 3 it will hleps you. If not, you can use it directly the property via css, also called order:x;

Comment: How do you want it to look on large screens? I don't follow.

Comment: @SergChernata, really?  I want it to look like exactly how I described in the first section and then elaborated with a screenshot and arrows.  Where are you not following.  There are two examples of what I want it to look like and another of what it currently looks like.

Comment: @KyleMit I see now, is there a lot of content in these sections or are they small?

Comment: @SergChernata, this is a simplified example for the purpose of demoing with minimal code.  There is a far amount of content in each section, in my real world scenario, but it shouldn't change the underlying structure and mechanics of repositioning the parent level divs

Comment: Imo there are 2 choices but I don't want to write it up if you're not interested: absolute positioning for large screens or using bootstrap's classes to hide and show duplicate section B div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with flexbox.

All three boxes need to be inside a flex container `display: flex;`. You then give all of the div's inside the flex container an order that kicks in using a media query in the desired screen width `order: 1;`.

The other main parts of the CSS are there to make sure that the three boxes are sized correctly into a column.

```
flex-direction: row;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-wrap: wrap
```

The HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex-container">
    <div id="sectionA" class="col col-sm-12 col-md-6 a">Section A</div>
    <div id="sectionAInfo" class="col col-xs-12 a">More Info about Section A</div>
    <div id="sectionB" class="col col-sm-12 col-md-6 b">Section B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap
  }
  #sectionA {
    order: 1;
  }
  #sectionAInfo {
    order: 3;
  }
  #sectionB {
    order: 2;
    float: right;
  }
}
```

A working codepen https://codepen.io/Washable/pen/zPoeqY?editors=1100